# Prove: If $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq C$, then $A \subseteq C$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-verification

Can someone tell me if this proof is acceptable?

Assume $A \not\subseteq C$. This means that there is an $x \in A$ such that $x \not\in C$. But since $\forall x \in  A: x \in B$ and $\forall x \in B: x \in C$ by the statement above, every $x \in A$ must also be in $C$. Thus, $A \subseteq C$ must be true.

Comment: Looks fine ${}{}{}{}$.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: It's fine, although there's not really any need to use a proof by contradiction; the same argument you have would show that every $x\in A$ also lies in $C$.

Comment: It's really not necessary to prove the contrapositive. You've directly proved that if $x\in A$ then $x\in C$ for all $x$, so you've proved that $A\subseteq C$. You don't need "Assume A\not\subseteq C$...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take your claim

> But since $\forall x \in  A: x \in B$ and $\forall x \in  B: x \in C$ by the statement above, every $x \in A$ must also be in C.

That's already a proof of your result!

So packaging that proof inside a longer argument which starts off by assuming the opposite of what you want to establish, and then aims for a contradiction, is just redundant.

This kind of redundancy might well be marked down by stern instructors (like me) as it suggests to an uncharitable reader that you aren't really following your own argument!

Comment: A mathematician I admire once told me (something like) "Write in a way that allows the reader to be as lazy as possible". As a reader, I don't want the extra layer of "contradiction" complexity unless there is good reason.

Answer (score 2):

It is okay. You could also do it directly: Take $x \in A$. Since $A \subseteq B$, we get $x \in B$. But $B \subseteq C$ implies that $x \in C$. So we conclude that $A \subseteq C$.